# While Loop to Request Pagination Link

Tags: python, python-2.6

I want to loop through pagination pages until I reach the last one. I search the page for the word pagination and as long as it's present I want my loop to continue. What I have now does not execute the portion inside the while loop. I've tested the condition statement separately to verify it returns True.

```
response = requests.get("someapi.api")
data = response.json()

while "pagination" in str(data) == True:
    print "Found string"
    response = requests.get(str(pag_object), timeout=5)
    data = response.json()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect. This is what you would want:

```
while "pagination" in str(data):
    # ...
```

*(At least for the condition, since you got structured JSON as a response there's probably cleaner ways to do this check, but that's not the point here).*

---

Your original condition doesn't work because under the hood, Python interprets it as

```
"pagination" in str(data) and str(data) == True
```

This is a consequence of all the comparison operators (including membership tests like `in`) having the [same precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and [chaining of comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

**Chaining** means you can write a common mathematical expression like `x < y < z` and it means what we usually think it does - `y` is between `x` and `z`. Or in other terms, `x < y AND y < z`.

However, applied to your original expression, this chaining leads to the surprising results you're seeing.

And this happens *even though* you tested part of your condition seperately, because the gotcha is in the specific composition of those sub-expressions. If you had written it by grouping the left part

```
("pagination" in str(data)) == True
```

like that, it would actually work - though it's unnecessary. Just doing `if item in sequence` is enough in Python, and much better style.

Comment: What do you mean by it's unnecessary? Would using `if item in sequence` continue until the item was no longer found?

Comment: Exactly - assuming you update `sequence` during the loop of course. In your case, your "sequence" is a string - Python treats strings as a sequence of characters, that's why you can do membership-tests like `if "foo" in "foobar"` for substring matching.

Comment: By unnecessary I mean that `"pagination" in str(data)` already evaluates to a boolean - so that's all you need for the condition in your `while` loop. Sure, `"(pagination" in str(data)) == True` also works, and also returns a boolean. But then why not do `"((pagination" in str(data)) == True) == True` to make sure it *really* is equal to `True`? ;-) In other words, there's no need to compare the result of a boolean expression to `True` again.

Comment: And to be clear: This gotcha you ran into here has nothing to do with this being a `while` loop - it's solely related to how expressions work in Python, and could have bitten you in any other context where you can use expressions.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the detailed explanation!